# Increase light contrast (shadows too bright, highlights too dark)

Tags: lighting, shadows

I'm trying to recreate this render:

[image: Reference Render]

But my render is coming out much darker:

[image: My Render]

I'm using the cycles renderer in the 2.8 beta. It's a sun light with a light gray world color. The colors are just colorpicked from the reference images. I notice that he has very sharp shadows here which would mean maybe using a smaller light source instead of a sun? I'm not really sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a brighter light source and less light on the environment to create contrast. In the world section bring down the strength for the background or make it a darker color.

Comment: ..and it does look like a sun-type light source .. you can adjust the size of a sun light, and therefore the sharpness of its shadows, in its data panel.

Comment: @cegaton the world strength tip made for much better shadows! Thanks! I had to find the strength option for the sun lamp under the "use nodes" button, but that's pretty much what did it.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange - you should answer your own question instead of editing it to include the answer.

Comment: @Samoth thanks! I was wondering how to close the thread haha

Comment: After some time waiting (for a possible better answer from somebody else) you can check your own answer so that it is accepted...

Comment: You should by now be able to accept your own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I darkened the world color found the sun lamp strength slider hidden behind the "use nodes" option. Both of these combined made for a much better render! Thanks!

[image: Updated Render]